# R: What's the best way to generate a clustered frequency chart here?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I just got started with R yesterday and have gotten along well on my own sofar, but now I'm stuck. The solution is probably easy, but your help would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to generate a bar graph of continents clustered by climate.
This is the data I have:

```
         country     continent   climate      mainuse
1           Iraq          Asia      Arid   Irrigation
2  United States North America Temperate     Industry
3       Pakistan          Asia      Arid   Irrigation
4         Canada North America Temperate     Industry
5     Madagascar        Africa  Tropical   Irrigation
6    North Korea          Asia Temperate Not reported
7          Chile South America      Arid   Irrigation
8       Bulgaria        Europe Temperate Not reported
9    Afghanistan          Asia      Arid   Irrigation
10          Iran          Asia      Arid   Irrigation
```

Code for the graph:

```
ggplot(rain2, aes(climate, continent, fill=continent)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

And this is what I get:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvbaq.png]

It is clustered, but what I'm looking to have displayed on the y axis is how frequently each continent was reported as having that climate. Using R has been very enjoyable sofar, but I'm not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ggplot(rain2, aes(climate, fill=continent)) +
       geom_bar(stat="bin", position=position_dodge())
```

The stat="bin" call makes R count the number in each "bin".

Your previous call to aes:

```
aes(climate, continent, fill=continent)
```

was interpreted as:

```
 aes(x = climate, y = continent, fill = continent)
```

Which resulted in continent being on the y axis. Removing the continent and changing stat to bin fixes it.

Comment: Thank you very much, jeremycg. I figured the solution would be easy, but not that easy. I can't upvote you yet, but you do deserve one. Have a nice day.